# Vertically stretch absolutely positioned div to size of page

Tags: css

I am trying to use the contents of an element as a page background. I can get this to work fine for the length of my browser window, but once content scrolls, the div stops.
http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/QXYDb/

html:

```
<html><head><title></title></head>
  <body>
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="content" style="height:900px;">Lorem Ipsum
      <br />...an arbitrary amount of content...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#content, #background {
  position:absolute;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left: 0;
}
#content {
  z-index:2;
}
#background {
  background:red;
  z-index:1;
}
```

I have tried variations of all the old faux-column tricks, but the problem with these is that the use the background to mask the differing heights - in this case the background is what has the difference.

I can do this easily with javascript, but I would be just tickled if i could do it with pure css. I've pounded on it for a few days and made no progress, so thanks for your thoughts.

Edit 1: I would like the background to scroll with the content, as in practice the background will contain content that repeats or that is potentially larger than the viewport as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/gquHF/

Answer (score 1):

Just position you background fixed in stead of absolute: http://jsfiddle.net/QXYDb/4/

The css looks like this:

```
#background {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
}
#content {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This causes the background to always stay in place, relative to the viewport.

Comment: This accomplishes the task of keeping the background up, but unfortunately gives a different visual effect than if the background scrolled with the text as opposed to over it. On my end, a solid background doesn't give this much context. Editing!